# ARKit 2.0 – How to combine ARAnchors in two ARWorldMaps?

Tags: swift, merge, arkit, aranchor

I need to combine a number of different `ARWorldMap` instances together. In other words, I need to create one instance with the combined anchors of the two (or more) instances of `ARWorldMap`.

I can share the same instance across the app, but it can be used differently by different groups of users, so I would eventually have to combine the same `ARWorldMap`instance but with different contents later anyway.

If `ARWorldMap`does this automatically, then would it be just a matter of distributing and updating the same instance?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that there is initially one world map that is shared then each user adds different content and you want to sync it?

Comment: @BlackMirrorz yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine occurences of ARWorldMap together. The way to do it is to load a previous one and update it with new data / anchors / feature points (extending the map).

Comment: Ok that could work, thanks. So with this approach I'd just have to combine the anchors array of both maps?

Comment: you would load the saved ARWorldMap to the AR configuration and then add anchors. Once again, that's extending a map, not combining several ones as you need to have the same origin.

Comment: hmm, so maybe converting the points based on the origin could solve that. Although that sounds like a major work? What's your thoughts? Thanks